# How to keep a div next to another div which is its parent

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6

I have two divs. One inside another. Both are independently draggable and if I move the Avatar div (moveablecontainer), the child div (box.opened) is programmed to follow it nicely. All that is fine and good.

BUT: What happens is if I resize the browser, the child div MOVES with the body of the browser and **does not** stay next to the Avatar div (moveablecontainer), its parent, which does not move at all unless I drag it.

**Here are the respective CSS of the two divs:**

**PARENT DIV**

```
.moveablecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 615px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px; 
  border: 0;
  height: 450px;
  max-height: 95px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

**CHILD DIV inside parent:**

```
.box {
   max-height: 0px;
 }
.box.opened {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 325px; 
  float: right;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}
.box.closed {
  display: none;
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

Here's the HTML (Abridged version) of the two divs:

```
<div class="moveablecontainer">
    <!--AVATAR GOES HERE-->  
    <div class="box opened">
    <!--CHAT WINDOW GOES HERE-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the two positions:

**INITIAL STATE:**

[image]

**BROWSER SMALLER:**

[image]

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

I want the chat window (CHILD) to stay with the Avatar (PARENT) no matter how I size/resize the browser.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best thing that you can do here is to create a parent div that contains both of the divs and then order them inside that div.  If the two items are meant to be together, then you don't really want one to be a child of the other.  It will take some reworking of the css.

```
<div class="moveablecontainer">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <!--AVATAR GOES HERE-->  
    </div
    <div class="box opened">
        <!--CHAT WINDOW GOES HERE-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lee, thanks, let me try it right now. Stand by - QUESTION: Make the childrend (chatbox and box opened) as absolute to the parent moveablecontainer?

Comment: I'm working with CSS on this Lee. Give me a bit. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: That is one way that you could do that.  Absolute positioning should work.  Then you can move the parent (containing the avatar and chat window) wherever you like it.